# Maximum ERC20 Tokens?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, tokens

What is the limit to the amount of ERC20 tokens someone can generate?
I tried to generate 1 Trillion tokens but only got 0.000001 Tokens back!

If anyone can make this more clear, I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you mean ERC20 tokens? Tokens amounts should expressed taking into account the decimals. For example if you have decimals = 2 then 1 token is stored as 100. From your numbers you have decimals = 18, if you want to assign yourselve 1 trillion you have to assign 1000000000000 * 10**18.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks that made it work! Post your reply as an answer and I will give you a checkmark! This is how I solved it in the end: uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 1000000000000*10**18; // 1 trillion tokens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tokens amounts should be expressed taking into account the decimals. For example if you have decimals = 2 then 1 token is stored as 100.

From your numbers you have decimals = 18, if you want to assign yourself 1 trillion you have to assign 1000000000000 * 10**18.